# Configure error for SharePoint alerts

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

In my SharePoint site I enabled alerts. The problem is that the alerts are activated for the users, but no emails are send to the users. I configured the central admin in correct way. I went through *[Troubleshooting SharePoint Alerts](http://sharepointalert.info/troubleshooting-sharepoint-alerts/)*, but no use. What is the actual one that is causing this?

I set the alert frequency to immediate.

Comment: How far did you get with the troubleshooting flowchart from the link?

Comment: Did you check the SMTP settings in Central Admin? Check Event Viewer for any detailed error.

Comment: i am not getting no emails. i checked the email infrastructure but i didnt found any issue with that. there is no anti virus running in the server.

Comment: yes, i configured the SMTP settings properly in Central Admin.

Comment: try sending a sample email from you web server using .net (may be a webpart or an application page) and see if you receive the email.

Comment: i sent a mail from that web server and i got the mails.

Comment: The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{61738644-F196-11D0-9953-00C04FD919C1}
 to the user NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE SID (S-1-5-20).  This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Comment: THAT IS GENERIC ERROR kindly let me know if you are attempting to send a mail to some other domain. kindly check if you are able to send a mail through workflow or when you  add a new person to the site

Comment: i am sending a mail to a user when a item is added or updated in discussion board list

Answer (score 1):

From first look I feel the problem is with your server where MOSS is installed. Kindly get your IT infrastructure team picture as it seems from your server you are not able to send mails. Follow the steps in *[Send Email via Telnet](http://www.rdpslides.com/webresources/FAQ00035_Send_Email_via_Telnet.htm)* to confirm what I'm saying.

Comment: when i am testing, i found the following error when i entered the command RCPT TO:abhimanyu.bits@gmail.com - 553 sorry that domain isn't in my list of allowed rcpthosts..

Comment: Get your IT team in picture your server needs to have those privilages

Comment: what priviliges does the server needs?

Comment: Get in touch with you IT Infrastructure team and tell your problem that you are not able to send email via telnet from your server Or post this query in some forum so that Experts from  windows OS community can help you out.